# make images bigger in Bootstrap Gallery

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Bootstrap Gallery](http://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/) but I want to change the dimension of small images.  I do element inspection and I see that they are autoxauto.  I can't figure out where the size is assigned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's using the size of the image file.  All of these images are `75x75` pixels.